# Access VBA: Before_Update Triggers Itself

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an MS Access database where I'm using the Before_Update() command to ensure prevent a user from pasting in data that doesn't match a specific validation list. Using Before_Update() I check against the list and cancel the entry if the value doesn't match, as well as popping up an error message. However, this cancellation re-triggers the Before_Update() which causes the message to come up again, which is very annoying. I'm stumped on a reliable way to remove the duplicate

```
 Private Sub ProductClass_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

 Dim strSQL As String
 Dim RS  As DAO.Recordset

 strSQL = "select * from pGroupList  where (ProductClass) = '" &     Me.ProductClass & "';"
 Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
 If RS.EOF Then
     MsgBox "Invalid Entry - Product Group", vbOKOnly, "Invalid Entry"
Cancel = True
End If
RS.Close
Set RS = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not set a flag variable when the cancellation is triggered. This can then be used to skip over the logic in the BeforeUpdate when it is called the second time

Comment: just do ProductClass.undo which will undo the edit mode

Comment: is there in Access any `Application.EnableEvents` property to be set to `True` or `False` as in Excel?

Comment: If you have validation set Access should handle all this for you

Comment: I can't get the flag approach to work because if I set a flag after canceling the entry, there is no suitable place to reset the entry. Either it never gets reset or it resets on "Before_Update" which is obviously pointless. The .undo command still lets data be pasted and enable events doesnt seem to exist in access.